# how to call a function that is received as prop in functional component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I am trying to call **toggleSideBar** received in **SideBar** component as a prop. But it is giving an error that **toggleSideBar** is not a function. Actually I am trying to call toggleSideBar in another callback function

Here is the code

```js
const Sidebar = (props) => {
  const { isOpenSidebar, toggleSideBar} = props;
  console.log(isOpenSidebar);
  const closeSideBar = () => {
    toggleSideBar()
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you please post an example of the parent to this functional component and how you are passing the function in there? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are not passing the function correctly in the component, make sure it should be like this

```html
<Sidebar toggleSideBar={yourActualFunction} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are passing function like this

```
<YourSidebar toggleSideBar={yourActualFunction()} />
```

Don't call the function while passing. Make it like this

```
<YourSidebar toggleSideBar={yourActualFunction} />
```